# Exporting SVG from Corel Draw to Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, path, corel-draw

I was working with a project, i need to export SVG or AI format from Corel Draw and I need to import it into the Illustrator , But If i design some filters or shadows in corel draw as path and when i exported as SVG and Imported in Illustrator , I am not getting the exact design of what i have designed in corel draw

I am designing as path in corel draw and design not so complicated , even the simple design makes much problem

Please help in the correct settings that i need to follow to export SVG or AI format from Corel Draw which works exactly in Illustrator

Comment: Why not just do it in illustrator to begin with?

Comment: Johannes it is all because i am having lots of designers who are not specialized in Illustrator but only Corel draw, But for my project, i need to import SVG in my application, that's the reason

Answer (score 1):

Corel to Illustrator does not go well, if you are using Illustrator, you should use it directly to create what you want.

If it was me i would import in illustrator and then redesign the things that are wrong.

But if you really want to use corel, export in PDF without flattening and then upload to illustrator and save in SVG.

Cheers

Comment: Yes thanks Nuno let me try and i will get back to you

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is not with Corel OR Illustrator, but with the SVG format, which does not support Corel's filters and shadows.

If all you need is to get your images from corel to illustrator and have no specific reason to use SVG, I recommend you try with another format, like eps, pdf, or you might even be able to export an .ai file directly from Corel. But beware, the filters might also be flattened or rasterized in the process.

Comment: Yes Spiral even i hope so that problem is in SVG not in tools let me try your process and i will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Better you can export from CDR to PS/EPS file which will be supported in both software.